# Difference between {Contract}Ref and Hash?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, openbrush

while contract instantiation inside constructor new function parameter, we can find `{Contract}Ref` and `Hash`. If new function accepts {Contract}Ref
as parameter, then type is `AccountId`

[image]

and if new function accepts Hash type is `Hash`.
I am confused about this. How they work and what is the difference between them using as `{ContractRef}` and `Hash`

```
#[ink(constructor)]
 pub fn new(accumulator: AccumulatorRef) -> Self {}

#[ink(constructor)]
pub fn new(accumulator: Hash) -> Self {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pallet_contracts you have a **two-step deployment of contracts**:

The contract code (Wasm blob) and the contract address + its storage are decoupled from each other. To deploy a non-existing contract on-chain:

- First, upload the Wasm contract on-chain (every contract Wasm code has a `code_hash` as an identifier).
- Second, instantiate the contract - it will create an `AccountId` and storage for that contract.
- Anyone can instantiate a new contract based on its `code_hash`.

So when you want to invoke contracts instances inside a contract you need to provide the code_hash of this contract (it should have previously uploaded on chain). It basically just creates a new `AccountId` referencing this contract Hash.

ContractRef however is just an `AccountId` (so a contract instance not a wasm blob stored and chain) and its callable messages functions that can be used for cross-contract calls. It is the equivalent of [wrapper in OpenBrush](https://docs.rs/openbrush/latest/openbrush/attr.wrapper.html)